# Calculate the magnitude and phase of a signal at a particular frequency in python

Tags: fourier-transform, python, frequency, phase, magnitude

I have a signal for which I need to calculate the magnitude and phase at 200 Hz frequency only. I would like to use Fourier transform for it. I am very new to signal processing. And this is my first time using a Fourier transform.

I found that I can use the `scipy.fftpack.fft` to calculate the FFT of the signal. Then use `numpy.mag` and `numpyh.phase` to calculate the magnitude and phases of the entire signal. But I would like to get the magnitude and phase value of the signal corresponding to 200 Hz frequency only. How can I do this using Python?

So far I have done.

```
from scipy.fftpack import fft
import numpy as np

fft_data = fft(signal)
magnitude = np.mag(fft_data)
phase = np.phase(fft_data)
```

Comment: Welcome to SE.SP!  Do you know the sampling frequency of your data?

Comment: the sampling frequency is 2 MHz

Comment: What do you have to separate it from?  What is the rest of the signal that is not 200Hz?

Comment: I'm not interested in other frequencies.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can find the index of the desired (or the closest one) frequency in the array of resulting frequency bins using [`np.fft.fftfreq`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.fft.fftfreq.html#numpy.fft.fftfreq) function, then use [`np.abs`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.absolute.html) and [`np.angle`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.angle.html) functions to get the magnitude and phase.

Here is an example using [`fft.fft`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.fft.fft.html) function from `numpy` library for a synthetic signal.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Number of sample points
N = 1000

# Sample spacing
T = 1.0 / 800.0     # f = 800 Hz

# Create a signal
x = np.linspace(0.0, N*T, N)
t0 = np.pi/6   # non-zero phase of the second sine
y = np.sin(50.0 * 2.0*np.pi*x) + 0.5*np.sin(200.0 * 2.0*np.pi*x + t0)
yf = np.fft.fft(y) # to normalize use norm='ortho' as an additional argument

# Where is a 200 Hz frequency in the results?
freq = np.fft.fftfreq(x.size, d=T)
index, = np.where(np.isclose(freq, 200, atol=1/(T*N)))

# Get magnitude and phase
magnitude = np.abs(yf[index[0]])
phase = np.angle(yf[index[0]])
print("Magnitude:", magnitude, ", phase:", phase)

# Plot a spectrum 
plt.plot(freq[0:N//2], 2/N*np.abs(yf[0:N//2]), label='amplitude spectrum')   # in a conventional form
plt.plot(freq[0:N//2], np.angle(yf[0:N//2]), label='phase spectrum')
plt.legend()
plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

And here is a useful manual with detailed explanations: [reference](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/routines.fft.html).

Comment: thank you for the clear explanation. I have two doubts. 1. What should I do if I want to change the phase of the signals to 30 degrees? 2. Why are you not scaling the magnitude values with (2/N)?

Comment: @thileepan 1. The phase t0 would be an additional term in the argument of a sine: A*sin(wt+t0). t0 = np.pi/6 should shift the signal to 30 degrees. 2. The example shows the default fft results. You can normalize the magnitude by setting the "norm" parameter like this: yf = np.fft.fft(y, norm='ortho'). Btw, my bad, np.isclose does not work as intended. I will fix it in the answer.

Comment: @thileepan Regarding the normalization of the results, you may find [this question](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/66058/am-i-supposed-to-normalize-fft-in-python) to be helpful.

Comment: Silly question (probably): I ran the code, and the output for the phase is `phase: -0.2672456406675483`, but you had set it up to be `t0 = np.pi/6   # non-zero phase of the second sine`. This is `0.5235987755982988`. Why are they not the same?

Comment: @AntoniParellada No stupid questions on this site) If you look at the phase spectrum plot, you can see that non-zero values are spread through all spectrum. That is why you see the difference. Also you can see that amplitude plot also has non-zero values through all spectrum. This happens when sine frequencies are not the exact multiple of the fundamental frequency of the DFT vector space, which was 2pi/1000 in my example.

Comment: @megasplash Thank you!

Comment: @megasplash, but why the phase spectrum spreads all the frequency range? why it is not just a point corresponding to the frequency of interest?

Comment: @Curious Calculating DFT means that you represent the signal as a linear combination of multiples of a fundamental frequency (`0`, `f`, `2f`, `3f`, `4f`, ... , `(N-1)f`). When a sinusoid frequency in a signal is not an exact multiple of `f` it will get a contribution from every DFT coefficient to compensate that, which looks like non-zero values through the spectrum. This applies to both real and imaginary parts, i.e. to both amplitude and phase.

Comment: @megasplash, and this explains such a phase incursion during the whole frequency range?

Comment: @Curious This explains the expected phase values spread. There is also a numerical computation error, which will alter the phase values even if an amplitude has single non-zero values.