# How can I interpret the output of indexing an fft in python?

Tags: fft, magnitude

I am looking to determine whether a given audio file contains a certain frequency, similar to [this question](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/72005/calculate-the-magnitude-and-phase-of-a-signal-at-a-particular-frequency-in-pytho). However, as a beginner, I need help understanding the output.

If I am understanding the linked question correctly, we start by observing the fftfreq output, which is the x axis if understood graphically. Since my sampling rate is 44kHz, the fftfreq contains approximately 22,000 bins. If I wanted to query what magnitude occurred at 800hz, I would simply access `value = fftfreq_output[800]`, then index the actual fft values using this new value like so: `fft_output[value]`. However, I am confused by the values that are returned. My code is below:

```
from scipy.io import wavfile
from scipy.fft import fft, fftfreq
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

user_in = input("Please enter the relative path to your wav file --> ")
sampling_rate, data = wavfile.read(user_in)
print("sampling rate:", sampling_rate)

duration = len(data) / float(sampling_rate)
print("duration:", duration)

number_samples_in_seg = int(sampling_rate * duration)
fft_of_data = fft(data)
fft_bins_from_data = fftfreq(number_samples_in_seg, 1 / sampling_rate)
fft_bins_from_data = fft_bins_from_data[0:number_samples_in_seg//2]
fft_of_data = abs(fft_of_data[0:number_samples_in_seg//2])


value = fft_bins_from_data[800]
print(value)

output = fft_of_data[int(value)]

print(output)
```

inputing a random wav file of a conversation, my output is this:

```
6.1500615006150054
71544.37927836686
```

My questions are:

1. Am I properly indexing the fft_output?
2. How can I interpret these
   numbers to observe what is the magnitude of the signal at a
   frequency of 800hz?

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

no, it's the other way around: `value` contains the frequency that the 800th entry in your FFT represents.

Honestly, `fftfreqs` is not ... useful. An FFT of length $N$ *always* divides the sample rate in $N$ equal pieces, $\Delta f = \frac{f_{\text{sample}}}N$. With 0Hz being the 0.th element, and the $k$th element representing frequency $k\cdot \Delta f$.

So, if you want to know which bin represents a frequency $f$, you just divide that by $\Delta f = \frac{f_{\text{sample}}}N$ to get the number of the bin you should look into. Division by  $\frac{f_{\text{sample}}}N$ is the same as multiplication by $\frac N{f_{\text{sample}}}$.

So, not quite sure why there's a function for that.

Comment: Thank you very much! So, just to confirm, if I was looking for frequency 800hz, I could find that bin by computing: `800 * (number_samples_in_seg / fsample)` where fsample is equal to the sampling rate?

Comment: yep, as I wrote.

Comment: only that your `number_samples_in_seq` is ... strangely calculated. You should just use `len(data)`. Not `sampling_rate*(len(data)/sampling_rate)`...